# Calculated field - formula help

Tags: calculated-column

I am trying to improve my SharePOint skills, but really struggling with formulas and calculated values.

First my questions is does it matter if the calculated field is reading dropdown, check box or radio button?  I am building a Compliance Checklist that users will answer multiple questions.

I have 4 or 5 columns where the value will be "Not Relevant","Pass" or "Fail"  If all 5 display "Pass" and/or "Not Relevant" then I want my caluculated column to display "Pass".  If any of the 5 columns display "Fail" then I want my calculated column to display "Fail".

Is this too complex to put into a calculated formula??

Answer (score 1):

I would use `AND`

Create a column of the type `calculated` as you cannot make a default value for a text column that references other columns.

[image]

Then use a formula like this:

```
=IF( AND( IF(Title="Test",TRUE,FALSE), IF(OtherColumn="Derp",TRUE,FALSE) ), "Pass", "Fail")
```

Referencing all the columns you need.

Comment: I just suggest and as I feel it makes it easier to read, but as Ranjoe shows it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

IF([Column1]="Fail", "Fail", IF([Column2]="Fail", "Fail",IF([Column3]="Fail","Fail",IF([Column4]="Fail","Fail",IF([Column5]="Fail","Fail","Pass"))) ))

in essense i check every column if it fails and if it fails it would return fail else if non of the condition is correct it would result to a "Pass"

Comment: can you mark this as answer then? :)